# An algorithm for server to discover nodes automatically?

Tags: java, http, architecture

long time reader, first time asking question here.

The situation: we have a server and nodes architecture, where the nodes can be on the same or different machine and are used for load balancing. Currently when configured the nodes know where is the server (IP, port) and when started they begin sending HTTP post requests periodically (every T seconds) to server to notify it about their contact information (IP, port, ...). The server has a list of available nodes and once a node reports, its info is stored in the list. If a node fails to report within 2*T seconds, its entry is removed from the list. This way the server has fairly up-to-date info on what is available. This scheme proved to be much better than the previous one, where a config file was used and we often had to deal with wrong configurations.

The new condition: Due to security concerns (don't know the details) we need to make the nodes silent - they must not initiate a connection with the server, can only accept and respond.

Because of this our current algorithm is void and I am looking for new options to present to my team. I know the easiest solution would be to go back to static configuration, but I'd like to avoid that. I am looking for proposals, not in details, but a general idea how this can be accomplished and not necessary with HTTP protocol. I hope someone here may have an idea or had already solved such problem.

Thanks.

Comment: is connectionless UDP/multicast a possibility?

Comment: I've been thinking about it too, but have no experience with UDP and multicasting. Therefore I don't rule it out, as I do not know details of new security constrains. It has to be made smart however, so the network is not flooded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your nodes don't indicate to the server that they exist, your server will have to assume that they exist in certain locations, and then poll those locations to determine if the node is up or down.

This means your server will have to be configured manually, to gain the prior knowledge of where the nodes are located.  In the event that the server is not told about the existence of a node, it will not use it even if the node is available and idle.

Basically, if one can pick out the network traffic from the node to the load-balancing server, then one can pick out the network traffic from the load balancing server to the worker node.  So, with the new architecture, I would not really expect any increase in safety.

A much better solution would be to encrypt the traffic sufficiently such that no eavesdropper could deduce the contents of the messages, and to handshake in a manner such that even if an attacker broke the encryption and attempted to simulate either end of the connection, they would raise too many alarms in attempting to figure out the handshake.

Comment: Guess this is the best approach in my case. Thanks!